# Iterating on ResultSet in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I execute a query using jdbc against a SQL db, I get a ResultSet object in return. Say I want to iterate through each row returned in the ResultSet, and then do operations on each, my question is whether or not the initial iterating through the ResultSet would be handled by the Driver or the Executors?

For example, say I have a service where I want to handle many WordCount jobs in large batches. Perhaps I have a DB with the following schema:

```
JobId: int
Input: string(hdfs location)
Output: string (hdfs path)
Status: (not started, in progress, complete, etc.)
```

Every time my Spark application runs, I want to use jdbc to read from the DB and get every row where the status is "not started". This gets returned as a ResultSet and each result is basically parameters for Spark to run the WordCount on. When I iterate on the ResultSet,  does it get split up and the executors iterate over small chunks? Or does the driver handle iterating on each? If the former, what happens once I start loading DataFrames for the given input locations and running the necessary transformations and actions to get word count? Would the executors further split up the DataFrames to other executors for processing?

Sorry if this question is unclear, I'm still learning about Spark and having trouble wrapping my mind around some of this. As well, would this generally be considered a good approach to handling multiple requests in one large batch? Or is there a better way to go about doing this?

Thanks!